# How to reload() .py file at same folder?

Tags: python

I have two .py files in the same folder: `file1.py` and `file2.py`.

file1.py

```py
def hello():
    print("hello world")
```

file2.py

```py
from file1 import hello
reload(file1)
hello()
```

Why do I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'file1' is not defined
```

Comment: @n1c9: No. That will not help and will only open the way for more problems. This problem has nothing to do with `__init__.py`.

Comment: Also: as a complete aside, don't use `[tag:...]` for *formatting* purposes, that is meant for linking to a tag page on the site itself. You can use backticks instead, i.e. `\`file1.py\``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**from A import B** means that just import B which is in A. Not import A

You import hello() function not file1.

If you want to reload file1, just import file1.

like this:

```py
from imp import reload
import file1
reload(file1)
file1.hello()
```

Additionally, if you use python 3.X version, you need to add

**from imp import reload**

or

**from importlib import reload**

Answer (score 2):

`reload()` reloads a *previously* imported *module*.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload.

`from file1 import hello` only imports `hello()` which is a function, not a module.

Also, `reload(module)` is available for Python versions <= 3.3. For Python versions >= 3.4, use `importlib.reload(module)`.

The proper way is

```
import importlib

import file1

file1.hello()

importlib.reload(file1)
file1.hello()
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert but did you try this,

```
from file1 import hello as q
reload(q)
hello()
```

Comment: TypeError: reload() argument must be module